# How to fix bootstrap tab panels? They aren't properly switching tabs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to change tabs using bootstrap tab panels just like this example here: https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

This is my jsfiddle code with what I have tried to do: https://jsfiddle.net/u18vjL9a/2/

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li  role="presentation" class="active"><a class="selected" href="#searchtab1"aria-controls="searchtab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search Catalog</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#searchtab2" aria-controls="searchtab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search Databases</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#searchtab3"aria-controls="searchtab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search Website</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't link Bootstrap CSS and JavaScript file.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And there's some wrong codes that break the rule of Bootstrap.

1. `div.tab-content` has wrong id that is the same with first `tabpanel`.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="searchtab1" style="display: block;">
<!-- should be: -->
<div class="tab-content">
```

2. tabpanels other than first one should not have `.active`. And there's irrelevant style `display: none;`.

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active"  id="searchtab2" style="display: none;">
<!-- should be: -->
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="searchtab2">
```

Here's working snippet:

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#catalogSearch>input[type=text]:nth-child(1) {
  width: 60%;
}

.navbar-top ul.navbar-nav>li:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-top .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  background-color: #5a8577!important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 11px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #a0c1b0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
  color: #ffffff!important;
  background-color: #76a394!important;
}

#navbar ul.dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 0px -15px;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.nav-mobile .navbar-brand {
  display: none;
}


/**BUTTON**/

.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/**HEADER**/

#idM6HJx {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-top: 3px solid #729f90;
}

#idzBDxO {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#idSaPI0 {
  float: right;
}


/**hours widget div**/

#id1sZY4 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 95px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #D06F44;
  max-width: 280px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}


/**search widget div**/

#idVdBs6 {
  max-width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#idnUKr8 {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.headeraddress {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #537b6f;
}

ul#menu-top-links.top_nav {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.top_nav {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-inline-start: 0px!important;
}

ul.top_nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.top_nav li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

ul.top_nav li a {
  color: #537b6f;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

ul.top_nav li a:hover {
  color: #9ebeb4;
}

#header .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 264px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 15px 0 15px;
}

.headerright {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.floatright {
  float: right;
}

.top_search {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 70px;
}

.searcht {
  color: #3a3a3c;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.searcht ul {
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  list-style: none;
}

.searcht li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 1px;
  width: 130px;
}

.searcht ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  background: #729f90;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #FFF;
}

.searcht a.selected {
  background: #5a8577;
}

.searcht ul li a:hover {
  background: #9ebeb4;
}

#searchtab1,
#searchtab2,
#searchtab3 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.searchform {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header input[type=text],
#header input[type=password],
#header input[type=email],
#header textarea {
  font-family: arial, "Consolas", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.cataloginput {
  border: 1px solid #3d6d6c;
  color: #333;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 22px!important;
  line-height: 22px!important;
  margin: 0;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 0 0 0 4px;
  width: 220px!important;
}

.catalogselect {
  border: 1px solid #3d6d6c;
  color: #333;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 24px!important;
  line-height: 18px!important;
  margin: 0 8px 0 -2px;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 3px 1px 2px;
  width: 100px;
}

#header select {
  max-width: 90%;
}

.searchsubmit {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-style: none;
  color: #5a8577;
  float: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #3d6d6c;
}

.searchsubmit:hover {
  background-color: #D06F44;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
}

.searcht div {
  padding: 5px;
  clear: left;
  background: #5a8577;
  border-right: 0px solid #FFF;
  max-width: 390px;
}

.databaseselect {
  border: 1px solid #3d6d6c;
  color: #333;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 24px!important;
  line-height: 18px!important;
  margin: 0;
  outline: medium none;
  padding: 3px 1px 2px;
  width: 331px;
}

#searchtab3>form>input.searchinput {
  width: 89%;
}


/**FOOTER**/

#default_footer {
  display: none;
}

#footer {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footerhours {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f6f6f6;
}

.footer_bar_right {
  float: right;
}

.footer_bar {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.footer_bar a {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  opacity: .8;
}

.footer_bar a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

a.yahoo {
  background: url(/images/tile//socials.png) no-repeat -56px 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
}

a.google {
  background: url(/images/tile//socials.png) no-repeat -84px 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
}

a.twitter {
  background: url(/images/tile//socials.png) no-repeat -28px 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
}

a.facebook {
  background: url(/images/tile//socials.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  float: right;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}

.wireless {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  color: #f6f6f6;
}

.wireless img {
  margin-top: -3px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wireless a {
  color: #fff;
}


/**EVENTS LISTING PAGE**/


/*Events listing title*/

.events-right>h1,
.events-grid>h1 {
  font-size: 3.8em;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .events-right {
    margin-left: 260px;
  }
}


/*event listing date bar*/

.events-date-bar {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}


/*event listing title*/

.eelisttitle a {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*event listing date and time*/

div.eelisttime.headingtext {
  color: #2c3e50!important;
}


/*event listing short description*/

.eelistdesc {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.eventRegButton {
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

.events-day-title>.events-date-string>.headingtext,
.events-day-title>.events-date-range-string>.headingtext {
  color: #56585B!important;
}

.events-left .tab-content {
  background: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .events-details {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}


/*filters*/

#eventsearch {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.events-filter-row {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.events-view-row {
  padding: 5px 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .events-filter-row {
    max-width: 768px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/*filter buttons*/

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .events-views {
    max-width: 768px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}


/**EVENT PAGES**/


/*border above and below the date, time and location info*/

#id4VX3g .amh-row,
#idlw5ZC.amh-row.row {
  border-top: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  padding: 8px 0;
}


/*event page sub title*/

#idaiMWo h3 {
  color: #56585B;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  ;
  font-weight: 400;
}


/*event page date*/

#idm0vRo h4 {
  color: #2d3e4f;
}


/*event description*/

#idiga4D p {
  color: #56585B;
}


/*event short description*/

#idjLXfv .custom1 {
  color: #34485e;
  margin: 1em 0 0.5em 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}


/**** Upcoming Events widget ****/


/*widget title*/

#idsqaCW h4 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}


/*height of events listing widget*/

#idtvR3F .amev-event-list {
  height: 580px;
}


/*date string in upcoming events widget*/

.amev-event-time>.headingtext {
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.amev-event-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.amev-event-description .eventRegButton {
  font-size: 0.95em;
  margin-bottom: 0.3em;
}


/*my events login page*/

.ammev-login {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.amPopup {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}


/** RESERVE **/

.amnp-holder {
  padding: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .footerhours {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }
  .footer_bar_right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer_bar a {
    float: none!important;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 7px;
    margin-left: 7px;
  }
  .wireless {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 12px!important;
  }
  .wireless img {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 44px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 989px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  #header .logo {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  #header .logo img {
    max-width: 200px!important;
    height: auto!important;
  }
  #ideeodQ {
    width: 760px;
  }
  #id1sZY4 {
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .headeraddress {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1068px) {
  .navbar-top .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 9px 7px;
    font-size: 0.74em;
  }
  #id6b7GS {
    float: right;
  }
  #idawjaN,
  #id6b7GS {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  #ideeodQ {
    width: 470px;
  }
  #idzBDxO {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #idSaPI0 {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #id6b7GS {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #header .logo {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  #id1sZY4 {
    float: right;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 240px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  #idnUKr8 {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  ul.top_nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .floatright {
    float: none;
  }
  #header .top_search {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    max-height: 100px;
  }
  .headeraddress {
    float: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 200px) {
  #idawjaN,
  #id6b7GS {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #id6b7GS {
    float: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #ideeodQ {
    width: 300px;
  }
  #idSaPI0 {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #idnUKr8 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  #idzBDxO {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #idVdBs6 {
    max-width: 300px;
    float: none;
  }
  #header .logo {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  #header .logo img {
    max-width: 200px;
    height: auto;
  }
  #id1sZY4 {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .headeraddress {
    float: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul.top_nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .floatright {
    float: none;
  }
  #header .top_search {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 20px;
    max-height: 120px;
  }
  .searcht li {
    width: 99px;
  }
  .searcht ul a {
    padding: 4px 10px;
    line-height: 16px;
  }
  .cataloginput {
    width: 146px!important;
  }
  .catalogselect {
    width: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="searcht">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a class="selected" href="#searchtab1" aria-controls="searchtab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search Catalog</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#searchtab2" aria-controls="searchtab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search Databases</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#searchtab3" aria-controls="searchtab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Search Website</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="searchtab1">
      <form name="catalogSearch" target="_blank" method="post" action="" onsubmit="SubmitSearch()" class="searchform">
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="cataloginput" value="Enter keyword..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter keyword...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter keyword...';}">
        <select class="catalogselect" id="SearchBy">
          <option selected="selected" value="KW">Any Field</option>
          <option value="TI">Title</option>
          <option value="AU">Author</option>
          <option value="SU">Subject</option>
          <option value="NOTE">General notes</option>
          <option value="PUB">Publisher</option>
          <option value="GENRE">Genre</option>
          <option value="SE">Series</option>
          <option value="ISBN">ISBN</option>

        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="btnG" class="searchsubmit" value="Go">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="searchtab2">
      <form class="searchform" action="" method="POST">
        <select name="subjectid" class="databaseselect">
          <option class="inputbox2" value="business-resources">Business Resources</option>
          <option class="inputbox2" value="ematerials-ebooks-audio-books-videos">eMaterials - eBooks, Audio Books, Videos</option>
          <option class="inputbox2" value="health-and-science-resources">Health and Science Resources</option>
          <option class="inputbox2" value="history-and-geneaology-resources">History and Geneaology Resources</option>
        </select>
        <input class="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="Go">
        <input type="hidden" name="catsearch" value="1">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="searchtab3">
      <form class="searchform" method="get" action="">
        <input type="text" value="Search this Website..." name="s" class="searchinput" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search this Website...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search this Website...';}">
        <input type="submit" class="searchsubmit" value="Go">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```